# to focus on the window.open and current window

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

It seems simple but I did not find a way. 
I open a window:

a. I need that while opening the window is minimized. 
b. when finished loading, I need to be normalized and then focus on the parent window.

--Code

```
var openwindow = null;

$(function(){

    openwindow = window.open("http://www.domine.com", "winx", "width=200,height=30,toolbar=0,location=0,status=0,scrollbars=0,menubar=0,directories=0,resizable=0");

    //minimized -> openwindow

    $(openwindow).load(function(){
        //normalized -> openwindow
        ...
        //focus in current window
    });
});
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, open your popup in a very small size, then in the popup window:

On load finish:

```
window.resizeTo(screen.width,screen.height); //this would maximize it, set the numbers to 200,30 to match your requirement
window.parent.opener.focus();
```

Comment: the issue is that I have no control over the new window

Comment: you can resize the popup from parent but you will have no control on when it finishes loading then.
openwindow.resizeTo(winWidth,winHeight);

Answer (score 0):

In the `onload` event of your child window, you can call `window.opener.focus()` or `window.opener.document.focus()` to re-focus on the parent.  I'm not sure there's any way to minimize the child window *while* it's loading, however.